# Reassign an array (reference type) of classes indexes

Tags: c#, arrays, reference

Consider the following code:

```
//Written in a WPF project, simply attach the handler to a button for testing code.
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class A
    {
        public int X;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        A[] Collection = new A[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < Collection.Length; i++)
        {
            Collection[i] = new A();
        }

        Collection[0].X = 1;
        Collection[1] = Collection[0];
        Collection[0].X = 2;
        MessageBox.Show("Collection[0].X = " + Collection[0].X + ",   Collection[1].X = " + Collection[1].X);
        //The messagebox produces: "Collection[0].X = 2,   Collection[1].X = 2"
        //Wanted behaviour: "Collection[0].X = 2,   Collection[1].X = 1"
    }

}
```

Since the array of classes, Collection, is a reference type. Collection[0] points to same memory region that Collection[1] does.

**My question is, how can i "copy" Collection[0] values to Collection[1] so i get the following output:**

**"Collection[0].X = 2,   Collection[1].X = 1"**

Comment: Just to say - value types... If you make `class A` a `struct` instead it does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class you want to clone is as simple as in your example, you can use the MemberwiseClone method to create a shallow copy of your object. In order to do so, you need to implement a method in your class that accesses [MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as it is protected:

```
public class A
{
    public int X;

    public A Clone()
    {
        return (A) MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Then change the line

```
Collection[1] = Collection[0];
```

to

```
Collection[1] = Collection[0].Clone();
```

In more complex scenarios, you need to create a mechanism of your own that creates a deep copy of the object (e.g. manually creating new objects, using serialization).

See also the example in above link for details.

Comment: `MemberwiseClone` is `protected`, and is not usually available to the external caller (unless the method is in the same type)

Comment: @Markus: Excellent! Thank you so much, have been so frustrating knowing the issue but not being able to solve it because of my inexperience of writing code. Just waiting out the minute to mark the answer accepted.